# What regex needs to be used to insert the contents in between nth occurence of certain charcters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have conditional statements like

```
rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ][/if]'
```

or

```
rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ]
   [if value = "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"]
[/if][/if]'
```

or

```
rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ]
      [if value = "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"]
          [if value = "##company.Name##" Equal= "14thNov"]
[/if][/if][/if]'
```

Now i need to ensure that i am only inserting the content in between nth  occurrence of characters `][` .where n represents number of if condition. i.e. above statement will turn into

```
 rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ]--TEST--[/if]'
```

or

```
rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ]
   [if value = "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"]
--TEST--
[/if][/if]'
```

or

```
rulesadded='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ]
      [if value = "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"]
          [if value = "##company.Name##" Equal= "14thNov"]
--TEST--
[/if][/if][/if]';
```

Currently i am using following code to achieve this.

```
 rulesadded=rulesadded.replaceBetween(nth_occurrence(rulesadded, ']', rulesadded.split("[/if]").length-1)+1,nth_occurrence(rulesadded, '[', rulesadded.split("[/if]").length),'--TEST--');
```

and method for replaceBetween is:

```
 String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
            return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
        };
```

However this is not going to work if equal attribute have square braces in them.

Is there any other way to achieve this efficiently??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple regex and `replace` function  for replace the first `[/`

```
var insertContent = function(rule, content){
    if(rule.split('[i').length === rule.split('[/').length)
        return rule.replace(/\[\//, content+'[/');
}

insertContent(yourRule, 'yourContent');
```

**Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h6r8h6se/2/**

Comment: I have updated, it's undefined because the rule2 in jsfiddle have 2 [if] but just 1 [/if] (i have change this for test the condition) retry with the new link

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start + 1) + what + this.substring(end);
};
var rulesadded1='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ][/if]';
var rulesadded2='[if value = "##user.Name##" Equal= "Report1"  ][if value =   "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"][/if][/if]';
var rulesadded3='[if value = "##user.Name##"Equal= "Report1"  ][if value = "##user.CompanyName##" Equal= "14thNov"][if value = "##company.Name##" Equal= "14thNov"][/if][/if][/if]';

insertContent(rulesadded1,"--Testing--");
insertContent(rulesadded2,"--Testing--");
insertContent(rulesadded3,"--Testing--");
function insertContent (rule, content){
var regExp = /\[if(.*?)\/if\]/gi;
var split3 = regExp.exec(rule);
var len3 = split3[0].length;
rule = rule.replaceBetween(len3 - 6,len3 - 5,content);
alert(rule);
```

}

```
insertContent(yourRule, 'yourContent');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xkqsywry/11/